# Retrofit 2 and ASP NET Core 1 File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to upload a file with Retrofit 2, so far my code looks like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("Manage/Test")
Observable<Boolean> UploadFile(@Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\"") RequestBody file);
```

With the implementation being

```
File file = new File(something.getImageResourceLocation());
            RequestBody requestBody =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

            m_subscription = m_climbRestService.AddClimb(requestBody).otherRXJavaStuff();
```

This sends correctly upon looking at the requests with Charles proxy, an example raw request is:

```
    POST /api/climb HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=84fe196a-87b1-4965-9514-e8eb9c5c89b7
Content-Length: 28020
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.0.1
Host: 192.168.1.98:1142

--84fe196a-87b1-4965-9514-e8eb9c5c89b7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="image.png""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 27771

ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC      





   


ÿÛC

ÿÀà"ÿÄ   
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ    
ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?äè¢+òãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú¿Qëòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú<J( ( ( ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnkòâ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÛh¢(¢(¢+òãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú¿Qëòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú<J( ( ( ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnkòâ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÛh¢(¢(¢+òãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú¿Qëòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú<J( ( ( ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnkòâ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÛh¢(¢(¢+òãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú¿Qëòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú<J( ( ( ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnkòâ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÛh¢(¢(¢+òãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú¿Qëòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú<J( ( ( ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnkòâ¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÛh¢(¢(®#þcöjÿ£ðGþ6üvøiÙ«þÁøTÙÿñÚíëòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾Ú¿D?á¦?f¯ú8oáSgÿÇkà¯ÛKáÄ¯´÷~$| øy­ø§ÃÚØÿ³õßiS_Y]yvpÅ'<*ÈûdGFÁ8de<(çz+¶ÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ£þöÿ£yñ¿þ×ün8+¶ÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ£þöÿ£yñ¿þ×ün8+¶ÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ£þöÿ£yñ¿þ×ün8ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ÎïøfÚWþçÆÿøK^ñºûÛö+øðÓàçìÁá¿ÿ¾!èñöÏí
Äz¬67¶¾eìòÇæA3+¦èÝrUÕA}EqðÓ³Wý7?ð©³ÿã´ÃL~Í_ôpÞÿÂ¦ÏÿÐoEqðÓ³Wý7?ð©³ÿã´ÃL~Í_ôpÞÿÂ¦ÏÿÐoEqðÓ³Wý7?ð©³ÿã´ÃL~Í_ôpÞÿÂ¦ÏÿÐo_ðQù=/ÿÜ;ÿMöÕú!ÿ
1û5ÑÃx#ÿ
?þ;_~Ú_þ%|cý§¼Kñ#áÃÍoÅ>Ô~Çý®øsJúÊëË³)<¹áVGÛ":6  Ã#)ä@;Ñ]·ü3?í+ÿFóãü%¯?øÝðÌÿ´¯ýÏÿð¼ÿãtÄÑ]·ü3?í+ÿFóãü%¯?øÝðÌÿ´¯ýÏÿð¼ÿãtÄÑ]·ü3?í+ÿFóãü%¯?øÝðÌÿ´¯ýÏÿð¼ÿãtÄ×ê?üþL³Áÿ÷ÿÓÍ~wÃ3þÒ¿ôo>7ÿÂZóÿ×Þß±_ÄÏ?f
ü7ø½ñDð·tï¶hh^#Õa±½µó/g?2   ]7Fèë2®¬2$è+ÿý¿èá¼ÿMÿ£þcöjÿ£ðGþ6üv;z+ÿý¿èá¼ÿMÿ£þcöjÿ£ðGþ6üv;z+ÿý¿èá¼ÿMÿ£þcöjÿ£ðGþ6üv;zü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯ÑøiÙ«þÁøTÙÿñÚø+öÒøgñ+ãí=â_>k~)ðö£ö?ìýwÃT×ÖW^]1IåÏ
²>ÙÑ°NO ùÞí¿áÿi_ú7ÿá-yÿÆèÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ &í¿áÿi_ú7ÿá-yÿÆèÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ &í¿áÿi_ú7ÿá-yÿÆèÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ &¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnkó»þöÿ£yñ¿þ×ün¾öýþ&|4ø9û0xoá¿Åïz'¼C§}³ûCBñ«
í¯{<±ùLÊéº7G\uaA DQ\Gü4ÇìÕÿG
àü*lÿøíðÓ³Wý7?ð©³ÿã´ÛÑ\Gü4ÇìÕÿG
àü*lÿøíðÓ³Wý7?ð©³ÿã´ÛÑ\Gü4ÇìÕÿG
àü*lÿøíðÓ³Wý7?ð©³ÿã´Û×åÇügþOKÆ?÷ÿÓ}µ~ÃL~Í_ôpÞÿÂ¦Ïÿ×Á_¶Ã?_ÿiïüHøAðó[ñOµ±ÿgë¾Ò¦¾²ºòìáO.xUöÈpÈÊyPÎôWmÿÏûJÿÑ¼øßÿ   kÏþ7Gü3?í+ÿFóãü%¯?øÝq4WmÿÏûJÿÑ¼øßÿ   kÏþ7Gü3?í+ÿFóãü%¯?øÝq4WmÿÏûJÿÑ¼øßÿ   kÏþ7Gü3?í+ÿFóãü%¯?øÝq5úÿäÿ,ðýÄôãs_ßðÌÿ´¯ýÏÿð¼ÿãu÷·ìWñ3á§ÁÏÙÃ
þ/|CÑ<-â;íÚõXlom|ËÙåÌfWMÑº:ä«« ú"â?á¦?f¯ú8oáSgÿÇhÿý¿èá¼ÿMÿ Þâ?á¦?f¯ú8oáSgÿÇhÿý¿èá¼ÿMÿ Þâ?á¦?f¯ú8oáSgÿÇhÿý¿èá¼ÿMÿ Þ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«ôCþcöjÿ£ðGþ6üv¾
ý´¾üJøÇûOxâGÂß|=¨ýû?]ðæ5õ×gRysÂ¬¶DtlFSÈ">w¢»oøfÚWþçÆÿøK^ñº?áÿi_ú7ÿá-yÿÆè¢»oøfÚWþçÆÿøK^ñº?áÿi_ú7ÿá-yÿÆè¢»oøfÚWþçÆÿøK^ñº?áÿi_ú7ÿá-yÿÆè¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§üîÿgý¥èÞ|oÿµçÿ¯½¿b¿
>~Ìøoñ{âáoéßlþÐÐ¼GªÃc{kæ^Ï,~d2ºnÑ× e]XdHÑWÿ
1û5ÑÃx#ÿ
?þ;Gü4ÇìÕÿG  (¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢
(¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢
(¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢
(¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢
(¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢
(¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢
(¢
ýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹¯ËýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ m¢(¢(¢(¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjýG¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjñ*(¢
(¢?QÿáÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯ÿhÏÚ7ãOìñ§YýgÿÂ?á
ìÿÙ:Oö}½×çÛÇs/ïncVÝ,Ò7Ìç°0ôF¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨ÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¾£ýg/ßµ¿Á]öý¡¼ÿ    õÿ´kjßÚ¾q-´_º¶8l0Æ¿*íÉÉ$ÎúýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ þËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿäùoöý£~4þÈÿuÙçöyñü#þÐ>Ïý¤ÿgÛÝy}¼w2þöæ9%mÒÍ#|Îq»?Dkòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾ÚøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿèÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¼JößøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿèÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¼JößøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿèÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¼JößøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëê?ÙÇörø-û[üÑÿhoÚÁðx¿_ûGö¶­ý¡qkçùÛEû«i#vÃkò¨ÎÜIüï¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯ÿhÏÚ7ãOìñ§YýgÿÂ?á
ìÿÙ:Oö}½×çÛÇs/ïncVÝ,Ò7Ìç°0ôF¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨ÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¾£ýg/ßµ¿Á]öý¡¼ÿ    õÿ´kjßÚ¾q-´_º¶8l0Æ¿*íÉÉ$ÎúýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ þËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿäùoöý£~4þÈÿuÙçöyñü#þÐ>Ïý¤ÿgÛÝy}¼w2þöæ9%mÒÍ#|Îq»?Dkòãþ
3ÿ'¥ãûé¾ÚøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿèÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¼JößøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿèÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¼JößøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿèÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¼JößøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëê?ÙÇörø-û[üÑÿhoÚÁðx¿_ûGö¶­ý¡qkçùÛEû«i#vÃkò¨ÎÜIüï¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH£þËûÑÿËPÿäöÚ(Ä¿áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯ÿhÏÚ7ãOìñ§YýgÿÂ?á
ìÿÙ:Oö}½×çÛÇs/ïncVÝ,Ò7Ìç°0ôF¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨ÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿùøxÏí§ÿEÿ-ý?ÿëÄ¨ mÿþÚôYÿòßÓÿù¾£ýg/ßµ¿Á]öý¡¼ÿ    õÿ´kjßÚ¾q-´_º¶8l0Æ¿*íÉÉ$ÎúýGÿrÉx?þâ?úq¹ þËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢<KþËûÑÿËPÿä?áÜ¿±gýü¸5þH¯m¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢?;¿áî´¯ýþÿÁuçÿ%Ñÿpý¥èGðGþ¯?ù.¾\¢>£ÿ¸~Ò¿ô#ø#ÿ×ü^¥ðßöGøiûxx*Ïö¯ø½®kzw|SæhYørâl£û4gE+Çn²í,F|_¨ÿðNOù2ÏÿÜGÿN74ÄÃ£ÿf¯ú<oÿ?þD£þû5ÐñãüÙÿò%}IE|·ÿý¿èxñ¿þlÿùøtìÕÿCÇÿðcgÿÈõ%òßü:?öjÿ¡ãÆÿø1³ÿäJ?áÑÿ³Wý7ÿÁÿ"WÔPËðèÿÙ«þÿàÆÏÿ+Ë¾"þ×¿`ÿ^þÊ4=Qð÷¼¿ìûÏÛM5ìio$óbC'p¸EÂ$~õ¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjí¿áî´¯ýþÿÁuçÿ%Ñÿpý¥èGðGþ¯?ù.¾\¢>£ÿ¸~Ò¿ô#ø#ÿ×üGü=Ãöÿ¡Áø.¼ÿäºùrúþáûJÿÐàü^ò]ð÷ÚWþàºóÿëåÊ(ê?ø{í+ÿB??ð]yÿÉuê_
ÿd·¬ÿjÿÚæ·§xÅ>gö.!Ê?³Höqùi4R¸Ìvè[.ÙbÄ`ÁUúÿäÿ,ðýÄôãs@Gü:?öjÿ¡ãÆÿø1³ÿäJ?áÑÿ³Wý7ÿÁÿ"WÔPËðèÿÙ«þÿàÆÏÿ(ÿGþÍ_ô<xßÿ6ü_RQ@-ÿÃ£ÿf¯ú<oÿ?þD£þû5ÐñãüÙÿò%}IE|·ÿý¿èxñ¿þlÿù¼»â/íqñ+öñ¥ïì¡ðCÑ5x[ËþÏ¼ñ´Ó^ÉöÖòO1á$8w\(PrA'ïZü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ÛþáûJÿÐàü^ò]ð÷ÚWþàºóÿëåÊ(ê?ø{í+ÿB??ð]yÿÉtÃÜ?i_úüÿëÏþK¯( ¨ÿáî´¯ýþÿÁuçÿ%Ñÿpý¥èGðGþ¯?ù.¾\¢>£ÿ¸~Ò¿ô#ø#ÿ×ü^¥ðßöGøiûxx*Ïö¯ø½®kzw|SæhYørâl£û4gE+Çn²í,F|_¨ÿðNOù2ÏÿÜGÿN74ÄÃ£ÿf¯ú<oÿ?þD£þû5ÐñãüÙÿò%}IE|·ÿý¿èxñ¿þlÿùøtìÕÿCÇÿðcgÿÈõ%òßü:?öjÿ¡ãÆÿø1³ÿäJ?áÑÿ³Wý7ÿÁÿ"WÔPËðèÿÙ«þÿàÆÏÿ+Ë¾"þ×¿`ÿ^þÊ4=Qð÷¼¿ìûÏÛM5ìio$óbC'p¸EÂ$~õ¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjí¿áî´¯ýþÿÁuçÿ%Ñÿpý¥èGðGþ¯?ù.¾\¢>£ÿ¸~Ò¿ô#ø#ÿ×üGü=Ãöÿ¡Áø.¼ÿäºùrúþáûJÿÐàü^ò]ð÷ÚWþàºóÿëåÊ(ê?ø{í+ÿB??ð]yÿÉuê_
ÿd·¬ÿjÿÚæ·§xÅ>gö.!Ê?³Höqùi4R¸Ìvè[.ÙbÄ`ÁUúÿäÿ,ðýÄôãs@Gü:?öjÿ¡ãÆÿø1³ÿäJ?áÑÿ³Wý7ÿÁÿ"WÔPËðèÿÙ«þÿàÆÏÿ(ÿGþÍ_ô<xßÿ6ü_RQ@-ÿÃ£ÿf¯ú<oÿ?þD£þû5ÐñãüÙÿò%}IE|·ÿý¿èxñ¿þlÿù¼»â/íqñ+öñ¥ïì¡ðCÑ5x[ËþÏ¼ñ´Ó^ÉöÖòO1á$8w\(PrA'ïZü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ÛþáûJÿÐàü^ò]ð÷ÚWþàºóÿëåÊ(ê?ø{í+ÿB??ð]yÿÉtÃÜ?i_úüÿëÏþK¯( ¨ÿáî´¯ýþÿÁuçÿ%Ñÿpý¥èGðGþ¯?ù.¾\¢>£ÿ¸~Ò¿ô#ø#ÿ×ü^¥ðßöGøiûxx*Ïö¯ø½®kzw|SæhYørâl£û4gE+Çn²í,F|_¨ÿðNOù2ÏÿÜGÿN74ÄÃ£ÿf¯ú<oÿ?þD£þû5ÐñãüÙÿò%}IE|·ÿý¿èxñ¿þlÿùøtìÕÿCÇÿðcgÿÈõ%òßü:?öjÿ¡ãÆÿø1³ÿäJ?áÑÿ³Wý7ÿÁÿ"WÔPËðèÿÙ«þÿàÆÏÿ+Ë¾"þ×¿`ÿ^þÊ4=Qð÷¼¿ìûÏÛM5ìio$óbC'p¸EÂ$~õ¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjí¿áî´¯ýþÿÁuçÿ%Ñÿpý¥èGðGþ¯?ù.¾\¢>£ÿ¸~Ò¿ô#ø#ÿ×üGü=Ãöÿ¡Áø.¼ÿäºùr(¢+õþ    Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢ûkþãÿW#ÿÿuÑÿqÿ«ÿËKÿºëíª(â_øsý\þZ_ý×@ý±ÿáßñ_ð­¿á-ÿKþfí°}«í_é¿ê<|½¿hÙþ±³³wÚ>Ú¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjößø|wý[wþ]¿ýÉGü>;þ­»ÿ.ßþä¯h ¶¿áñßõmßùvÿ÷%ðøïú¶ïü»û¾%¢>ÚÿÇÕ·åÛÿÜÃã¿êÛ¿òíÿîJøûkþÿVÝÿoÿrP?cøxüeïü,øD¿á,ÿû#íÿeû/úúÿ:/3wÙ÷ÿ«\oÛÎ7kõþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ<KþãÿW#ÿÿuÑÿqÿ«ÿËKÿºëíª(â_øsý\þZ_ý×Gü9Çþ®Gÿ-/þë¯¶¨ áÎ?õr?ùi÷]ðçú¹ü´¿û®¾Ú¢>%ÿ8ÿÕÈÿå¥ÿÝtÛþ÷ÿÿ
ÛþßøD¿æ`þ×ûÚ¾Õþþ£ÉËÛöë;7q£íªü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ mÿÇÕ·åÛÿÜÃã¿êÛ¿òíÿîJøûkþÿVÝÿoÿrQÿÿ«nÿË·ÿ¹+âZ(í¯ø|wý[wþ]¿ýÉGü>;þ­»ÿ.ßþä¯h ¶¿áñßõmßùvÿ÷%ö8ÿÿÆ^ÿÂÉÿKþÏùÿ²>ßö_²ÿ¡¯ó¢ó7}úµÆý¼ãqø¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÄ¿áÎ?õr?ùi÷]ðçú¹ü´¿û®¾Ú¢>%ÿ8ÿÕÈÿå¥ÿÝtÃêäòÒÿîºûjøþãÿW#ÿÿuÑÿqÿ«ÿËKÿºëíª(â_øsý\þZ_ý×@ý±ÿáßñ_ð­¿á-ÿKþfí°}«í_é¿ê<|½¿hÙþ±³³wÚ>Ú¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjößø|wý[wþ]¿ýÉGü>;þ­»ÿ.ßþä¯h ¶¿áñßõmßùvÿ÷%ðøïú¶ïü»û¾%¢>ÚÿÇÕ·åÛÿÜÃã¿êÛ¿òíÿîJøûkþÿVÝÿoÿrP?cøxüeïü,øD¿á,ÿû#íÿeû/úúÿ:/3wÙ÷ÿ«\oÛÎ7kõþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ<KþãÿW#ÿÿuÑÿqÿ«ÿËKÿºëíª(â_øsý\þZ_ý×Gü9Çþ®Gÿ-/þë¯¶¨ áÎ?õr?ùi÷]ðçú¹ü´¿û®¾Ú¢>%ÿ8ÿÕÈÿå¥ÿÝtÛþ÷ÿÿ
ÛþßøD¿æ`þ×ûÚ¾Õþþ£ÉËÛöë;7q£íªü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ mÿÇÕ·åÛÿÜÃã¿êÛ¿òíÿîJøûkþÿVÝÿoÿrQÿÿ«nÿË·ÿ¹+âZ(í¯ø|wý[wþ]¿ýÉGü>;þ­»ÿ.ßþä¯h ¶¿áñßõmßùvÿ÷%ö8ÿÿÆ^ÿÂÉÿKþÏùÿ²>ßö_²ÿ¡¯ó¢ó7}úµÆý¼ãqø¿Qÿàòeÿ¸þnhÄ¿áÎ?õr?ùi÷]ðçú¹ü´¿û®¾Ú¢>%ÿ8ÿÕÈÿå¥ÿÝtÃêäòÒÿîºûjøþãÿW#ÿÿuÑÿqÿ«ÿËKÿºëíª(â_øsý\þZ_ý×@ý±ÿáßñ_ð­¿á-ÿKþfí°}«í_é¿ê<|½¿hÙþ±³³wÚ>Ú¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjößø|wý[wþ]¿ýÉGü>;þ­»ÿ.ßþä¯h ¶¿áñßõmßùvÿ÷%ðøïú¶ïü»û¾%¢>ÚÿÇÕ·åÛÿÜÃã¿êÛ¿òíÿîJøûkþÿVÝÿoÿrP?cøxüeïü,øD¿á,ÿû#íÿeû/úúÿ:/3wÙ÷ÿ«\oÛÎ7kõþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ<KþãÿW#ÿÿuÑÿqÿ«ÿËKÿºëíª(â_øsý\þZ_ý×Gü9Çþ®Gÿ-/þë¯¶¨ ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ    Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ( ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí«õ¿.?à£?òz^1ÿ¸wþí¨Ä¨¢(¢(¢+õþ  Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ¿.+õþ   Éÿ&YàÿûÿéÆæ=¶( ( ÿáî³Wýþ7ÿÁuÿ%Ñÿpý¿èGñ¿þ¬ÿù.¿;è Ñø{ìÕÿB?ÿð]gÿÉuåßd_·/jÿæ§x{Å>_ö}î&ö?³F¶ryR ÌîWÙR¤àÈúÿäÿ,ðýÄôãs@-ÿÃ£ÿi_ú<ÿÏþD£þûJÿÐñàüÞò%~Ñ@ßðèÿÚWþàÆóÿ(ÿGþÒ¿ô<x#ÿ7ü_¢4Pçwü:?öÿ¡ãÁø1¼ÿäJ?áÑÿ´¯ýÿÁçÿ"WèùÝÿý¥èxðGþo?ù½Ká¿íqðÓöðUì¡ñ{CÖõø[ÌþÐ¼ðå´3YIöò?-æ'8t
\0`2'ëúü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¨ÿáî³Wýþ7ÿÁuÿ%Ñÿpý¿èGñ¿þ¬ÿù.¿;è Ñø{ìÕÿB?ÿð]gÿÉtÃÜ?f¯úüoÿë?þK¯Îú(ôCþáû5ÐãüYÿò]ð÷Ù«þÿàºÏÿëó¾ýÿ¸~Í_ô#øßÿÖü^]ñöGøûxxÒ÷ö¯øA®hw¼SåÿgÙøâhocû4kg'Å*Énåpí*N  |_¨ÿðNOù2ÏÿÜGÿN74òßü:?öÿ¡ãÁø1¼ÿäJ?áÑÿ´¯ýÿÁçÿ"WèùÝÿý¥èxðGþo?ùøtí+ÿCÇ?ðcyÿÈú#E~wÃ£ÿi_ú<ÿÏþD£þûJÿÐñàüÞò%~Ñ@ßðèÿÚWþàÆóÿ+Ô¾þ×
?`ÿYþÊ´=oQñ¼ÏíÏ[C5iï#òÞibsç@ÙEÃ ~¿¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjúþáû5ÐãüYÿò]ð÷Ù«þÿàºÏÿëó¾ýÿ¸~Í_ô#øßÿÖüGü=Ãöjÿ¡Æÿø.³ÿäºüï¢?D?áî³Wýþ7ÿÁuÿ%Ñÿpý¿èGñ¿þ¬ÿù.¿;è Ñø{ìÕÿB?ÿð]gÿÉuåßd_·/jÿæ§x{Å>_ö}î&ö?³F¶ryR ÌîWÙR¤àÈúÿäÿ,ðýÄôãs@-ÿÃ£ÿi_ú<ÿÏþD£þûJÿÐñàüÞò%~Ñ@ßðèÿÚWþàÆóÿ(ÿGþÒ¿ô<x#ÿ7ü_¢4Pçwü:?öÿ¡ãÁø1¼ÿäJ?áÑÿ´¯ýÿÁçÿ"WèùÝÿý¥èxðGþo?ù½Ká¿íqðÓöðUì¡ñ{CÖõø[ÌþÐ¼ðå´3YIöò?-æ'8t
\0`2'ëúü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¨ÿáî³Wýþ7ÿÁuÿ%Ñÿpý¿èGñ¿þ¬ÿù.¿;è Ñø{ìÕÿB?ÿð]gÿÉtÃÜ?f¯úüoÿë?þK¯Îú(ôCþáû5ÐãüYÿò]ð÷Ù«þÿàºÏÿëó¾ýÿ¸~Í_ô#øßÿÖü^]ñöGøûxxÒ÷ö¯øA®hw¼SåÿgÙøâhocû4kg'Å*Énåpí*N  |_¨ÿðNOù2ÏÿÜGÿN74òßü:?öÿ¡ãÁø1¼ÿäJ?áÑÿ´¯ýÿÁçÿ"WèùÝÿý¥èxðGþo?ùøtí+ÿCÇ?ðcyÿÈú#E~wÃ£ÿi_ú<ÿÏþD£þûJÿÐñàüÞò%~Ñ@ßðèÿÚWþàÆóÿ+Ô¾þ×
?`ÿYþÊ´=oQñ¼ÏíÏ[C5iï#òÞibsç@ÙEÃ ~¿¯Ëø(Ïüîÿ¦ûjúþáû5ÐãüYÿò]ð÷Ù«þÿàºÏÿëó¾ýÿ¸~Í_ô#øßÿÖüGü=Ãöjÿ¡Æÿø.³ÿäºüï¢?D?áî³Wýþ7ÿÁuÿ%Ñÿpý¿èGñ¿þ¬ÿù.¿;è Ñø{ìÕÿB?ÿð]gÿÉuåßd_·/jÿæ§x{Å>_ö}î&ö?³F¶ryR ÌîWÙR¤àÈúÿäÿ,ðýÄôãs@-ÿÃ£ÿi_ú<ÿÏþD£þûJÿÐñàüÞò%~Ñ@ßðèÿÚWþàÆóÿ(ÿGþÒ¿ô<x#ÿ7ü_¢4Pçwü:?öÿ¡ãÁø1¼ÿäJ?áÑÿ´¯ýÿÁçÿ"WèùÝÿý¥èxðGþo?ù½Ká¿íqðÓöðUì¡ñ{CÖõø[ÌþÐ¼ðå´3YIöò?-æ'8t
\0`2'ëúü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¨ÿáî³Wýþ7ÿÁuÿ%Ñÿpý¿èGñ¿þ¬ÿù.¿;è Ñø{ìÕÿB?ÿð]gÿÉtÃÜ?f¯úüoÿë?þK¯Îú(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(¢(¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§ü¸¯Ôø''ügÿî#ÿ§öÚ(¢
(¢
(¢
ü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶¯Ôzü¸ÿÿÉéxÇþáßúo¶ ¢(¢(ÿÙ
--84fe196a-87b1-4965-9514-e8eb9c5c89b7--
```

The server is simple, it runs on ASP.NET Core 1 with an API controller taking a `IFormFile` as an input, the problem is this is always null. I have checked `Request.Form.Files` and this is also null, there is however always the correct content length for the `Request.Body` meaning the packet is being sent, just not being recognised by the server.

The server method is as follows

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile myfile)
        {
            if (Request.Form.Files != null && Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
            {

            }

            if (myfile != null)
            {
                // do something here with uploaded file
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                // cannot procede without a file to upload
                return HttpBadRequest();
            }
        }
```

Does anybody have any experience with uploading a file with Retrofit 2 and ASP NET 5/ ASP NET Core (whichever people are calling it) and might know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, the problem being

```
Observable<Boolean> UploadFile(@Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png\"") RequestBody file);
```

should not have the filename escaped like that, should more be like

```
Observable<Boolean> UploadFile(@Part("myfile\"; filename=\"image.png") RequestBody file);
```